# Where is the Iron Golem Spawning area HEIGHT centered?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Ok, I understand that Iron Golems spawn in a 16x16x6 area (6 being the height) from the center of the village. Does this mean the two blocks of the door, two blocks below the door and two blocks above the door? OR! does it mean 6 blocks from the bottom of the door?

From the picture below, which accurately depicts the spawning height for Iron Golems, A or B? (assuming all doors are at the same level)

A source would also be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 16x16x6 area is centered around the center of the village. The center of the village is geometric mean of coordinates of all doors that are part of the village. The door coordinates are usually carried by the bottom part of the door.

If all doors are at the same Y coordinate, the area would be centered vertically around the bottom edge of the doors (so neither A nor B in the picture is correct).

[image: C]

Source: Minecraft Source Code via Minecraft Coder Pack (MCP) 9.10